# Having troubles with the subset function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, statistics, subset

I have finished to write a shiny app, the problem is that when I run it certain combinations of plots between different element of the column "country" of the data.frame aren't shown. I figured out this is because the `subset()`function isn't working properly. I will put my code for the app here:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#a)
load("wind.Rdata")
windAT <- subset(wind,wind$country=="AT")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Wind Capacity"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "country1",
                  label = "Select country",
                  choices = unique(wind$country),
                  selected = "AT"),
    sliderInput(inputId = "year",
      min = 1980,
      max=2016,
      value = c(1990,2010),
      step=1,
      label="Select a year interval for the data"
    ),
    selectInput(inputId = "country2",
                label = "Select another country",
                choices = unique(wind$country),
                selected = "BG")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Time Series",plotOutput(outputId ="time_series")),
      tabPanel("Scatterplot",plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot"))
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$time_series <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=subset(wind, country==c(input$country1,input$country2) & input$year[1]<=year & 
                              year <= input$year[2]), 
           aes(x=time,y=capacity,colour=country))+
      geom_line()+
      ylab("Power capacity")+
      xlab("Time")
  })
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({ ggplot(data=subset(wind, wind$country==c(input$country1,input$country2) & input$year[1]<=wind$year & 
                                             wind$year <= input$year[2]), 
                               aes(x=day,y=capacity,colour=country))+
    geom_point()+
    ylab("Power capacity")+
    xlab("Calendary year")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I noticed the problem is of the function subset because when I do

```
subset(wind,country==c("AT","BG"))
```

the function returns just the rows of "wind" which have "AT" in the "country" column and not also the observations which have "BG" in this column.
This doesn't happen if I ask to subset observations with a different country value with "AT" and the function works well for "BG2 values on their own or with different countries like for instance:

```
subset(wind,country==c("BE","BG"))
```

this works fine.
How could I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `subset(wind, country %in% c("BE", "BG"))`? If you use `==` with two vectors of unequal length it will use vector recycling to try and match the lengths, i.e. it will just repeat  `"BE", "BG", "BE", "BG", "BE", "BG"` until it matches the number of rows of `wind`, checking odd rows agains BE and even rows agains BG.

Comment: Thank you, so every time I'm comparing between two vectors of unequal length I should use `%in%` with the vector I'm comparing on the right hand side?

Comment: Usually yes, but read the linked duplicates for more information on the difference between `==` and `%in%`. Also see `?match`.

Comment: @Axeman  I would have answered to the effect that "unequal lengths" was a complete misunderstanding of the principle to be used to make that decision. Rather the question should be set membership (used by `%in%`) versus element by element comparison which would be the principle used by `==`. Case in point: the results of `letters[1:10] == letters[10:1]` versus `letters[1:10] %in% letters[10:1]`